# My jquery function doesn't work with django

Tags: jquery, html, django

Can't run jquery with my django html page.

I tried to run with html and it's work. But with django nothing happens.

Here's my main_page.html :

```html
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/blog.js' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="text" style="display:inline" id="Textarea" ></textarea>
          <textarea class="text" style="display:inline" disabled="disabled" id="Textarea2"></textarea>

        </div>
        <button>Translate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my blog.js file under static/js/blog.js :

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#Textarea2").hide();
  });
});
```

I expect for the Textarea2 to hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<link>` is not for javascript, you need a `<script>` tag

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'js/blog.js' %}">
```

To

```
<script src="{% static 'js/blog.js' %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your setting.py has `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
2. Set the STATIC_ROOT setting to the directory from which you’d like to serve these files `STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"`
3. Run the collectstatic management command: `python manage.py collectstatic`